# Flatten collection of key-collection items Linq

Tags: c#, linq

How would I go about flattening below structure using Linq?

[image]

I'm looking at following result:

```
Date      Ids
1/1/2011  1
1/1/2011  2
1/1/2011  3
1/1/2012  3

etc..
```

I tried SelectMany, but I'm doing it wrong. Some snippets for this example:

```
public class DTO
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<int> Ids { get; set; }
}
```

as

```
var dataSet = new List<DTO>{
    new DTO {Date = new DateTime(2011,1,1), Ids = new List<int>{1,2,3} },
    new DTO {Date = new DateTime(2012,1,1), Ids = new List<int>{3,4,5} },
    new DTO {Date = new DateTime(2013,1,1), Ids = new List<int>{5,6,7} }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selectmany should be on the lists inside the DTO but while keeping a reference to the date. That's probably the main issue. By using query syntax those constructions are a lot easier:

```
var res = (from s in dataSet
    from id in s.Ids
    select new {Date=s.Date, Id = id}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking to `SelectMany`

```
var result = dataSet.SelectMany(x => x.Ids, (dto,id) => {
    return new { date = dto.Date,id};
});
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/GHY67873

Comment: thank you, I like this answer very much as well as it uses lambdas so likely will be my preferred choice.

Answer (score 1):

And yet another `SelectMany` variant with an inner `Select`

```
var result = dataSet.SelectMany(x => x.Ids.Select(id => new { date = x.Date,id}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want `Ids` as list you can do

```
var newDataSet = from dto in dataSet
                 from id in dto.Ids
                 select new DTO { Date = dto.Date, Ids = new List<int> { id }};
```

If you want a single `id` property like

```
public class NewDTO
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

You can do

```
var newDataSet = from dto in dataSet
                 from id in dto.Ids
                 select new NewDTO { Date = dto.Date, Id =  id };
```

Answer (score 0):

Here another solution using SelectMany

```
            var results = dataSet.Select(x => new
            {
                dto = x.Ids.Select(y => new
                {
                    date = x.Date,
                    id = y
                })
            }).SelectMany(x => x.dto).ToList();
```